# bq load error due to datetime with milliseconds

Tags: google-bigquery

Is there an option for bq load to specify datetime format to parse? I'm getting an error when using bq load due to a datetime with milliseconds in it.

Sample file below:

```
ID|Card|Status|ExpiryDate|IssuedDate
1105|9902|Expired|2015-12-31 00:00:00|2014-07-04 14:43:41.963000000
```

Command used below:

```
bq load --source_format=CSV --skip_leading_rows 1 --field_delimiter "|" --replace mytable $GSPATH
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not possible to control/change date or datetime formatting when loading data into BigQuery.

As a solution, I would try to load the datetime field as a STRING and then try to use the PARSE_DATETIME function or something else to postprocess and convert the string to datetime.

An example of the code to parse the string to datetime:

```
select PARSE_DATETIME('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%E*S','2014-07-04 14:43:41.963000000');
```